# Getting 'Could not find stored procedure' error calling SQL Server stored procedure in Node JS from AWS RDS database

Tags: node.js, sql-server, amazon-rds

We always normally work in Azure where I write around 200 stored procedures a year in their SQL Server database.

We had to create a SQL Server database in AWS-RDS and still call it in our Node APIs like usual. I was able to quickly and easily set up the AWS DB in SQL Server Management Studio so I do know the credentials.

I created several tables and several stored procedures with no problems and tested to make sure they worked there. When I called them like I normally do in Node, I found I was getting an error

> Could not find stored procedure

I went through forums all over but most of the data pertains to MySQL instead of SQL Server, and after trying everything I saw in the forums have not been able to complete what should be a very simple process. I would imagine there is some simple thing I missed, but after 2 days it is time for some fresh ideas.

I am setting up the credentials like this:

```
var awsConnection = {
    host     : process.env.RDS_HOSTNAME,
    user     : process.env.RDS_USERNAME,
    password : process.env.RDS_PASSWORD,
    port     : process.env.RDS_PORT
};
```

I am using the endpoint provided by AWS for the host, the username and password I use to login to SQL Server Management Tool (which works). The port number is the one specified by AWS (1433 - the default for SQL Server).

I call it in my api like this:

```
await sql.connect(connectionAWS).then(pool => {
    // Stored procedure   
    console.log("awsConnection INSIDE: " + JSON.stringify(awsConnection));
    return pool.request()
        .input('repId', sql.VARCHAR(40), repObj.RepID)
        .execute('UserExistsBD');
      }).then(async result => { ...
```

I added the console.log to see if we were getting past the login and it appears that we do. I also used Telnet to make sure the endpoint/port combo work and they do. I also checked AWS to make sure the Subnets, Route tables, and gateways were good and to make sure my IP Address was white listed. Any ideas would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure that Node is connecting to the correct Server? The correct database? I don't see a database name mentioned in the connection details, so it will be using whatever the "default database" setting is configured for the SQL Login at the server.

Comment: I had mentioned 'I am using the endpoint provided by AWS for the host, the username and password I use to login to SQL Server Management Tool (which works). The port number is the one specified by AWS (1433 - the default for SQL Server).' In my notes above. The endpoint provided by AWS includes the database name in it in a format like this DatabaseName.instanceId.AWSLocation.com. I wanted to make sure I was hitting the correct DB. because a bad DB name would be the most likely reason for this error.